# .Net framework 4.6 stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0, .net-4.6

I have been using Visual Studio 2015 Preview and C# 6 features for a few months. This week the .Net framework 4.6 (displays in control panel as 4.5.3) suddenly stopped working, with the effect of C# 6 syntax sugar is no longer compiling.

This was most likely caused by the fact that the preview license has expired, however I am not able to find a fix for that. Installing a Visual Studio 2015 Release Candidate did not help. Trying to uninstall and re-install the .Net framework 4.6 did not help either - I get the error ".NET Framework 4.5.3 Preview or a later update is already installed on this computer." when trying to re-install the framework.

Can anyone help with resolving the issue?

Comment: Hmya, that happens with very early beta versions.  Good thing you used a VM so you can just throw it away and create a fresh new one.

Comment: Temporary fix: switching the project to .Net framework 4.5.2 allows the project to compile with C# 6 syntax sugar.